# clarify some things about culasparse

Tags: cuda, cula

Checking  [this](http://www.culatools.com/cula_sparse_programmers_guide/) example (API example at the end), I want to ask a few questions.

1) In the example we are supplying matrix a with non zero elements.What is the real size of the matrix though?And these are the elements of the matrix or the positions that contain non zero elements?

2) Can I use at the calculations (use in a function like  culaSparseSetDcooData)  a matrix A which will contain zero and non zero elements?
If I want to create a sample matrix just to test ,should I have to create a matrix with zero elements,then fill it with some elements and then?

Comment: Reg 1, can you be more specific? Which examples? Can you paste part of the code here?

Comment: @selalere:The API example that it has at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding 1) Interestingly, the size of the matrix in COO format is not explicitly specified: It consists of coordinates of the non-zero elements of the matrix. If you have a COO matrix with 1 non-zero element, then this could be

```
double a[1] =  { 1.0 };
int colInd[1] = { 10 };
int rowInd[1] = { 20 };
```

and (as you can tell from the row/column indices) describe elements of a matrix that has *at least* size 11*21, or it could be

```
double a[1] =  { 1.0 };
int colInd[1] = { 1000 };
int rowInd[1] = { 2000 };
```

and describe elements of a matrix that has *at least* size 1001*2001

However, in this example, it seems like this is a quadratic matrix, and `n=8` seems to be the size. (Unfortunately, there seems to be no detailed documentation of the `culaSparseSetDcooData` function...)

Regarding 2) This is not entirely clear. If your question is whether the "non-zero" values *may* (in reality) have a value of `0.0`, then I can say: Yes, this should be allowed. However, the example that you referred to already shows how to create a simple test matrix.

Comment: :For 1).So,we can only tell the "at least size".For 2) I meant ,that if we can pass as argument to a culla function a matrix which contains both zeros and non zero elements.

Comment: Unless the algorithm itself does not require the values to be !=0, I can not think of a reason why a value (even if it is technically called a "non-zero" in the matrix) should not be 0.0